# Command line notebook

Tags: python, javascript, html, reinventing-the-wheel, dom

I used Python and a little bit of JavaScript using the (Python) modules [Dominate](https://github.com/Knio/dominate) and Flask to create a web app that somewhat resembles the Jupyter Notebook though with very basic functionality. I would like my notebook to execute only Windows command prompt commands. I have tried to implement the basic functionality of adding terminal cells that can be executed, reused and removed. I would like to expand and improve it although if possible, still maintaining the Dominate module functionality.

```py
import os

import dominate
from dominate.tags import script, a, label, textarea, input_, link, div, form, pre
from dominate.util import raw
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
doc = dominate.document()
filepath = "render2.html"
outp = ""
inpt = 1


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template(filepath)


@app.route("/run", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def result():
    global outp
    toRun = request.form.to_dict()["cmd"]
    outp = os.popen(toRun).read()
    return render_template(filepath, outp=outp)


@form(id="cellList", action="/run", method="POST")
def cell():
    global inpt
    a("Add cell", onclick="""let cln = document.getElementById('cellList').cloneNode(true);
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(cln);
let preOut = document.getElementsByClassName("output");
preOut[preOut.length - 1].innerHTML = '';
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let inputCount = parseInt(input.innerHTML.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]);
input.innerHTML = input.innerHTML.replace(inputCount, inputCount + 1);""",
      cls="btn btn-primary", role="button")
    a("Remove cell", onclick="""let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
if (container.childElementCount > 1) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
}
/*
let outputLbl = document.getElementById("outputLbl");
let outPutLblCount = parseInt(outputLbl.innerHTML.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]);
outputLbl.innerHTML = outputLbl.innerHTML.replace(outPutLblCount, outPutLblCount + 1);*/
""",
      cls="btn btn-primary",
      role="button")
    div(label("In [%d]: " % inpt, fr="cmd", id="input"))
    textarea(cls="form-control", id="cmd", name="cmd")
    input_(value="Submit", type="submit", cls="btn btn-primary", id="submit", role="button")
    pre(raw("""{% if outp %}
{{ outp }}
{% endif %}"""), style="background-color: lightgray", cls="output", id="output")


with doc.head:
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js")

with doc:
    container = div(cls="container", id="container")
    with container:
        cell()
        script("""
$('input.btn.btn-primary').each(function (i) {
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('SUBMIT');
        let formData = 'cmd=' + $('#cmd').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/run',
            data: formData,
            success: function (results) {
                //console.log(results);
                $('pre#output').html(results);
            }
        })
    });
});
""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("templates/render2.html", "w") as fopen:
        fopen.write(doc.render())
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**render2.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dominate</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <form action="/run" id="cellList" method="POST">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="let cln = document.getElementById('cellList').cloneNode(true);
document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(cln);
let preOut = document.getElementsByClassName(&quot;output&quot;);
preOut[preOut.length - 1].innerHTML = '';
let input = document.getElementById(&quot;input&quot;);
let inputCount = parseInt(input.innerHTML.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]);
input.innerHTML = input.innerHTML.replace(inputCount, inputCount + 1);" role="button">Add cell</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
if (container.childElementCount &gt; 1) {
    container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
}
/*
let outputLbl = document.getElementById(&quot;outputLbl&quot;);
let outPutLblCount = parseInt(outputLbl.innerHTML.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1]);
outputLbl.innerHTML = outputLbl.innerHTML.replace(outPutLblCount, outPutLblCount + 1);*/
" role="button">Remove cell</a>
        <div>
          <label for="cmd" id="input">In [1]: </label>
        </div>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="cmd" name="cmd"></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" role="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <pre class="output" id="output" style="background-color: lightgray">{% if outp %}
{{ outp }}
{% endif %}</pre>
      </form>
      <script>
$('input.btn.btn-primary').each(function (i) {
    $(this).on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('SUBMIT');
        let formData = 'cmd=' + $('#cmd').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/run',
            data: formData,
            success: function (results) {
                //console.log(results);
                $('pre#output').html(results);
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```